# How can I verify that Polipo is caching?

Tags: proxy, cache

I'm making requests to several thousand unique URLs on each run of a JVM program, and I want to cache the requests.

I've got Polipo up and running, and I've configured my Java app to proxy HTTP requests through it. I have verified that when Polipo isn't running the program can't make requests, so I'm sure that Polipo is proxying.

I want Polipo to cache every request, and I want to verify that. The relevant bits of my config file:

```
diskCacheRoot = "~/.polipo-cache/"
maxDiskEntries = 1000000
```

From my reading of the documentation that should be enough. But after running the program through the proxy once, `~/.polipo-cache/` remains empty and the contents of the log file are only:

```
Disabling local tree: No such file or directory
Established listening socket on port 8123.
Vary header present (Accept).
Vary header present (Accept).
Vary header present (Accept).
Vary header present (Accept-Encoding).
...
...
...
```

How can I be sure that my requests have been cached for next time?

Comment: Did you add the correct proxy options to the program you are using? With the default polipo settings, you can test this by using `http_proxy=127.0.0.1:8123 curl http://google.com`. Then check in you polipo cache directory. In my case, I see a "google.com" entry, showing polipo worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try requesting the same URL twice from your program and check tcpdump / wireshark to ensure it is only requested once?